# How to init some variables but leave others undefined yet in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to use the init() {} because I have some variables I want to init, but in the same time I want to pass some variables for that view, it seems like I need to do one or another, is there an way I can achieve both goals?

```
// Variables for detecting scroll position
let onScrollingStarted: () -> Void
let onScrollingFinished: () -> Void

init() {
    let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
    self.publisher = detector.debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .dropFirst()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    self.detector = detector
}

let passedMood: moodPics
```

I want do leave the passed mood as it is but init the two onScrolls

Comment: What’s the nature of these properties? Should they be provided by a caller as arguments to the initializer?

Comment: the detector I'm initializer it to find out scroll position later, but the passed mood, I want to pass it when I call this view from another view through a navigation view

Comment: You'll have to make them optional, so they can be initialized in the initialize (to `nil`), then you can set them later. If you're coming in from a navigation view, I'm guessing that's probably because you need this view to represent one kind of thing or another, and that might need multiple properties. You'll probably want to package up all the fields into a single model object, and keep a nilable property for it that you set upon navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the concept of using different init(). It turns out that each init is a giving different options to choose from when initing or calling or creating an object of this view or struct.

```
init() {
    let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
    self.publisher = detector.debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .dropFirst()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    self.detector = detector
    self.passedMood = .aggressive
}

init(passedMoood: moodPics) {
    let detector = CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>(0)
    self.publisher = detector.debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .dropFirst()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    self.detector = detector
    self.passedMood = passedMoood
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of `init()` and just have `init(passedMood:moodPics = .aggressive)`.   Note that by convention it should be `MoodPics` with a capital for types such as structs, classes and enums

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).